# Regex that checks if string only contains numbers and special characters

Tags: python, regex, if-statement

I am trying to make an if function that checks if a string contains only a mixture of numbers and any special characters. For example:

```
Input: "Hello"
>>> False

Input: "$34&@!5^"
>>> True

Input: "Hello34#&%"
>>> False
```

I'm new to Regex and I'm not sure how to write the Regex for this. I know checking for special characters is `r'^[_\W]+$'` , and `isdigit()` can be used to check numbers only, but how do I combine both? I'm confused on how to combine `[0-9]` and the other symbols to write a Regex for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `^[\W0-9_]+$` to match all non-word characters, `_`, and `0-9`.